# How do I install ubuntu server OS without internet?

Tags: archive

I donwloaded ubuntu server 14. 
I tried to install the server on my desktop and I get this error "Bad archive mirror".
I tried skipping the step but the system still brings me back to this error. Someone please help.

Comment: I am wondering how to fix that too.